# Java Regex replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, parsing

The following code parses a polynomial expression by removing the variable term, exponentiation operator, and degree in order to determine the coefficients of the polynomial.

Code:

```
String expression = "x^10 + 6x^2 + 9";

expression = expression.replaceAll("(\\^\\d)?", ""); //fix
expression = expression.replaceAll("x", "(1)");

System.out.print(expression);
```

Result:

```
(1)0 + 6(1) + 9 //intended result: (1) + 6(1) + 9
```

If the degree of a term >= 10, the method will simply remove the first digit of the degree. Is there any way to replace the entire number (in this case, 10).

Answer (score 2):

This should cover as well numbers with more than one digit. (+ after d)

```
    String expression = "x^10 + 6x^2 + 9";

    expression = expression.replaceAll("(\\^\\d+)?", ""); //fix
    expression = expression.replaceAll("x", "(1)");

    System.out.print(expression);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `+` after the `\d`.
`+` indicates one or more repetitions.

```
expression = expression.replaceAll("(\\^\\d)?", ""); //fix
```

becomes

```
expression = expression.replaceAll("(\\^\\d+)?", ""); //fix
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is only selecting one digit. Add a `+` to select atleast one digit: `\\^\\d+`